# Serialize object fields with extra data not included on object

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm new to Jackson so I'm sort of figuring out how to use the resource properly. Basically, I have an object and I'd like to be able to serialize & deserialize the fields of the object. In addition, I want to add some extra data to the JSON that isn't included in the Object's fields. So in other words, I want to serialize an object's fields, and then add some extra data on top of those fields. For deserialization, I want to deserialize the fields normally, and then I'd have some extra logic to handle the extra data I added.

I wrote a custom serializer that does this:

```
public class TestObjectJSONSerializer extends StdSerializer<TestObject> {

public TestObjectJSONSerializer() {
    super(TestObject.class);
}

@Override
public void serialize(TestObject value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
    JavaType javaType = serializers.constructType(TestObject.class);
    BeanDescription beanDesc = serializers.getConfig().introspect(javaType);
    JsonSerializer<Object> beanSerializer = BeanSerializerFactory.instance.findBeanOrAddOnSerializer(serializers, javaType, beanDesc, true);

    gen.writeStartObject();

    // This function will serialize all the fields
    beanSerializer.unwrappingSerializer(null).serialize(value, gen, serializers);

    gen.writeObjectFieldStart("hologram");
    gen.writeObjectField("location", value.getSubObject().getWorld());
    gen.writeObjectField("lines", value.getSubObject().getLines());
    gen.writeEndObject();

    gen.writeEndObject();
}
```

}

This seems to get the job done well, although I have my doubts that this is the "correct" way to do this since I'm using what looks to be Jackson internals.

I also wrote a corresponding deserializer:

```
public class TestObjectJSONDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<TestObject> {

public TestObjectJSONDeserializer() {
    super(TestObject.class);
}

@Override
public TestObject deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
    JavaType javaType = ctxt.constructType(TestObject.class);
    BeanDescription beanDesc = ctxt.getConfig().introspect(javaType);
    JsonDeserializer<?> beanDeserializer = BeanDeserializerFactory.instance.createBeanDeserializer(ctxt, javaType, beanDesc);

    TestObject testObject = (TestObject) beanDeserializer.unwrappingDeserializer(null).deserialize(p, ctxt);

    // Deserialize the "hologram" object
    JsonNode node = p.getCodec().readTree(p);
    JsonNode hologramNode = node.get("hologram");

    // Deserialize "location" and "lines" fields from the "hologram" object
    String worldName = p.getCodec().treeToValue(hologramNode.get("location"), String.class);
    List<String> lines = p.getCodec().treeToValue(hologramNode.get("lines"), ArrayList.class);

    // Set the deserialized values in the FakeNPC object
    testObject.setSubObject(new TestSubObject(worldName, lines, 5));

    return testObject;
}
```

This ends up throwing `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: No _valueDeserializer assigned`. I did some debugging and it seems that the createBeanDeserializer function constructs the BeanProperties with a FailingDeserializer which is causing this error.

I'm assuming there is probably a much better way to be doing this that I'm unaware of, please let me know!

Thanks!